# CAS and Non Blocking Counter

Tags: java, concurrency

I have been reading JCIP by Brian Goetz. He explains the implementation of a non-blocking counter using CAS instruction. I could not understand how the increment is happening using CAS instruction. Can anyone help me understand this.

```
public class CasCounter {
    private SimulatedCAS value;

    public int getValue() {
        return value.get();
    }

    public int increment() {
        int v;
        do {
            v = value.get();
        }
        while (v != value.compareAndSwap(v, v + 1));
        return v + 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`value.compareAndSwap(v, v + 1)` is equivalent to the following, except that the entire block is atomic: (see [compare-and-swap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compare-and-swap) for details)

```
int old = value.val;
if (old == v) {
  value.val = v + 1;
}
return old;
```

Now `v = value.get()` gets the current value of the counter, and if nobody else is trying to update the counter at the same time, `old == v` will be true, so the value is set to `v+1` (i.e. it is incremented) and `old` is returned. The loop terminates since `v == old`.

Suppose someone else incremented the counter just after we did `v = value.get()`, then `old == v` would be false, and the method will immediately return `old`, which is the updated value. Since `v != old` now, the loop continues.

Answer (score 3):

The `compareAndSwap()` method will perform the following operations atomically:

```
- determine if `value` is equal to `v`
- if so, it will set `value` to `v+1`
- it returns whatever `value` was when the method was entered (whether or not `value` was updated)
```

The caller can check to see if `value` was what they expected it to be when the called `compareAndSwap()`.  If it was, then the caller knows it's been updated.  If it wasn't what was expected, the caller knows that it wasn't updated, and will try again, using the 'new' current value of `value` as what's expected (that's what the loop is doing).

This way, the caller can know that the increment operation doesn't get lost by some other thread that tries to modify `value` at the same moment.